# Generation, adding, editing and deleting by the same button in the same textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a code for a winform button, that either generates a random line from a text file or lets me add a new sentence to this file. (depending on what radiobutton is active).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           string FilePath = @"C:\file.txt";

if (radioButtonNew.Checked)
      {
           string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
           Random rand = new Random();
           string SentNew = Lines[rand.Next(0, Lines.Length)];
           TextBox.Text = SentNew;
      }

     else
      {
        File.AppendAllText(FilePath, TextBox.Text + environment.NewLine);
        MessageBox.Show("Value added"); 
      }
```

But for example I don't like one of random results and want not just to add another one.. **But rather to correct a generated result, then press a button again and change a line.**

**Or I want to delete a generated line from the file at all.** Can it be done within the same button and same textbox by just adding two more radio buttons?

I am not sure how to do it, can you help? My goal is to have random generation, adding my own (these I have), editing and deleting of generated lines. The problem is - I don't quite know **how to tell a program to edit or delete this random line it just generated to a textbox.**

Comment: Yes you can.  Store the **Index** value generated by `rand.Next()` at class level (outside of the click event) so you know where in the file the line came from.  Now read the file in and put it into a List<String> instead of an Array.  This will allow you to edit that entry **and/or** remove it from the List<>.  To update the file use `File.WriteAllLines()`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick (untested) example of what I described in my comments above:

```
    private Random rand = new Random();

    private int Index = -1;
    private List<String> Lines = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FilePath = @"C:\file.txt";

        if (radioButtonNew.Checked)
        {
            Lines = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(FilePath));
            Index = rand.Next(0, Lines.Count);
            label1.Text = "Index: " + Index.ToString();
            TextBox.Text = Lines[Index];
        }
        else if (radioButtonAppend.Checked)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(FilePath, TextBox.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            Lines = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines(FilePath));
            Index = Lines.Count - 1;
            label1.Text = "Index: " + Index.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Line added");
        }
        else if (radioButtonModify.Checked)
        {
            if (Index >= 0 && Index < Lines.Count)
            {
                Lines[Index] = TextBox.Text;
                File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, Lines);
                MessageBox.Show("Line Modified");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Line Selected");
            }
        }
        else if (radioButtonDelete.Checked)
        {
            if (Index >= 0 && Index < Lines.Count)
            {
                Lines.RemoveAt(Index);
                File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, Lines);
                Index = -1;
                label1.Text = "Index: " + Index.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Line Deleted");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Line Selected");
            }
        }
    }
```